# Static Variable Not overriding in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5, static, maatwebsite-excel

Let Me remodify my question what i acheiving, I am using plugin in laravel maatwebsite-excel v3.1. I am export the eloquent collection in a excel sheet.

In this code, i am trying to create multiple sheet with different style on the individual sheet, i refer in the plugin website, that there is an event in the library to do aftersheet is created. check this link (https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.0/exports/extending.html)

Code:

```
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle; 
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeWriting;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeExport;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeSheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;

    class Export implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithTitle, WithEvents {

        use RegistersEventListeners;

        protected static $sheet = '';

        public function __construct($sheet) {
           self::$sheet = $sheet;

        }

        // This event function will trigger every time new instance is created.
        public static function AfterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
        {
           if(self::$sheet =='First') {
              //Changing cell style
           }
           if(self::$sheet =='Second') {
              //Changing cell style
           } 
        }

  }
```

Call:

```
$a = new Export('First'); //in the event function it has to echo "title1" but it is echoing "title2"
$b = new Export('Second');
```

I am not able to get `First` value in the `AfterSheet()` event method within the class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is incomplete code. Where did you call `event()` in the first place? Also, `static` variables remains the same across all class instances because it is class level, not instance level. So, if you change once, it gets changed forever. Why do you think it would maintain previous values?

Comment: As vivek_23 says, when you create two instances of Export, what you are actually doing is changing the value of a single title property that is static on the class. If you want each instance to retain their own value, you need to remove all static references from your class.

Comment: Sounds like `static` works as expected. It's unclear why you expect something else.

Comment: You are overwriting value check here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b22387c3fd304b7bfe4d5d4a1c491895380fca1f

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it assumes you want each instance to retain it's own value;

```
class Export {

private $title = '';

public function __construct($title) {
   $this->title = title;

}

public function getTitle() {
    return $this->title;
}

}

$a = new Export("title1");
$b = new Export("title2");

echo $a->getTitle() . ' ' .  $b->getTitle();
```